# FCM Notification in iOS doesn't play sound when received

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase push notifications in my iOS Application. Although I am able to send the notification by sending below payload, it doesn't play a sound when received.

```
{
    "to": "myToken",
    "notification": {
        "body": "test",
        "title": "test"
    },
    "priority": "high"
    "sound": "default"
}
```

If I send the test message from console, it works well and plays notification sound. 
 **Note**:

1. My Authorization code is correct
2. I am sending http request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`
3. I have tested it on IPhone 4 , IPhone 6 and IPhone 6S, All recieve
   notifications without sound

Comment: i am getting notifications from fcm . now , i want to make functionality such as when i will get notification from fcm , app should play a sound file without even touching notification message . do you know how to do that ? didRecieveRemoteNotification will only get executed when user tap on notification . i want to play a sound file like alarm tune when i get the notification . please guide me through it .

Answer (score 73):

your JSON `"sound" : "default"` should be inside the `"notification"` key not in the root of the JSON. This JSON should work.

```
{
    "to": "myToken",
    "notification": {
         "body": "test",
         "title": "test",
         "sound": "default"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: I am having the same structure on server but still on some devices sound file is not playing when app is in background.

Comment: i am getting notifications from fcm . now , i want to make functionality such as when i will get notification from fcm , app should play a sound file without even touching notification message . do you know how to do that ? didRecieveRemoteNotification will only get executed when user tap on notification . i want to play a sound file like alarm tune when i get the notification . please guide me through it .

Comment: where should this json file exist ?
because i'm testing the notification via ui firebase.com , so how can i send this payload with sound?

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. Would you please provide the source of your answer? Thank you.

Comment: @DuncanJones, actually, your answer didn't work for me with iOS 12.1 but putting `sound:'default'` in the non-device-specifc `notification` object ultimately worked for me.

Comment: but it takes only two arguments (title and body) if you do it without json: `Message.builder()
    .setNotification(new Notification(
        "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
        "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day."))` https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Comment: Attention, this is only true if you use legacy api, and not http v1 api. see this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Answer (score 44):

When using the [FCM admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages), you have to specify sounds separately for Android and Apple devices:

```
let message = {
    notification: {
        'body': 'This is the message the user sees',
    },
    data: {
        'param1': 'specify some extra data here',
    },
    // Apple specific settings
    apns: {
        headers: {
            'apns-priority': '10',
        },
        payload: {
            aps: {
                sound: 'default',
            }
        },
    },
    android: {
      priority: 'high',
      notification: {
          sound: 'default',
      }
    },
    token: 'target FCM token goes here',
};
```

(Note: I've only tested the Apple settings thus far)

Comment: Good call - I haven't been able to find any info on getting notification sounds to work in IOS anywhere, didn't realise it was part of the APNS object! Cheers for this.

Answer (score 10):

```
    payload = {
        notification:{
            title: 'SOLO has been changed by an administrator',
            body: 'Administrator changed your SOLO schedule',
        },
        android: {
        },
        apns: {
            headers:{
                "apns-collapse-id": "solo_changed_administrator",
                "content-available": "1",
                "apns-priority": "10",
            },
            payload:{
                aps:{
                    sound: 'default',
                    badge: 12213123223
                }
            }
        },
        data:{
            type: 'type'
        }
    }
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages?authuser=0#ApnsConfig

Answer (score 3):

Using `firebase-admin` package for node js

```
    const message = {
        notification: {
          title: "This is title",
          body: "This is body",
        },
        apns: {
          headers: {
            "apns-priority": "10",
          },
          payload: {
            aps: {
              sound: "default",
            },
          },
        },
        android: {
          notification: {
            sound: "default",
          },
        },
        token: 'fcm-token'
    }


getMessaging()
    .send(message)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json({
        msg: "Sent successfully",
      });
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you build an application using Flutter, There are many possibilities for sound not to play

> 1. You may be using an older version of flutter_local_notifications
>    Please Update it to the latest.
> 2. Missing sound in apns payload

If you want to play a custom sound, you can add your sound file inside the resource in iOS and pass the file name conditionally inside the payload.

1. If you pass the **default** then the default ringtone will play.
2. If you pass **file name** which is inside iOS resources folder then that
   sound ring.

Code Example:

```
const message = {
    token: to,
    notification: {
      title,
      body,
      // sound: "ringtone.wav",
    },
    apns: {
      headers: {
        "apns-priority": "10",
      },
      payload: {
        aps: {
          sound:
            body != "You have one Booking Request"
              ? "default"
              : "ringtone.wav",
        },
      },
    },
    android: {
      priority: "high",
      notification: {
        channelId:
          body != "You have one Booking Request" ? "normal" : "Sound",
        sound: "ringtone.mp3",
      },
    },
    data: {
      click_action,
    },
  };
```

Replace **body != "You have one Booking Request" ? "default" : "ringtone.wav"** with your requirment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When notifications come through FCM to iOS not working sounds or vibrations. Here I followed this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1
And finally went successful. I created my apple notification as an alert in my payload and it works for me. Here is my JSON below to get some idea about my solution.

```
"apns": {
    "payload": {
        "aps" : {
            "alert" : {
                "body": "Notification body",
                "title": "Notification title"
            },
            "badge" : 2,
            "sound" : "default"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Please put this "apns" key in the relevant place of your message request. I was using REST call for requesting message.
Please refer the following link to get a good idea of how to send a notification message with platform-specific delivery options.
Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#example-notification-message-with-platform-specific-delivery-options